# How to invoke routed component in template in angular

Tags: angular

Angular 7, I have a component which responds to a route like this

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
            switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
                return this.myService.get(+params.get('id'));
            })
        )
            .subscribe( ...
```

Now in another component template, I want to invoke this component directly in the template, how do I do that?

```
<app-my></app-my>
```

How do I provide the routing parameter `id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use/add [`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) and use standard [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-).

**MyComponent.ts**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    id: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        if(!this.id)
        {
          this.route.paramMap.pipe(
                switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
                    return this.myService.get(+params.get('id'));
                })
            )
                .subscribe( ...
```

**root-component.ts**

```
<app-my [id]="'some value'"></app-my>
```